# Optional factory params that default if not specified

Tags: typescript

I have a factory function that takes an options type `FactoryOptions<T>`.

It specifies an optional `items` key which itself can be of type `Item[]` or `(defaultItems: Item[]) => Item[]`

The goal is to allow the user to specify their own `items` array, leave it `undefined` and have it default to a fixed array, or specify a function that takes the default array and returns their own as a return value.

```
function factory<T extends AnyItems = DefaultItems>(options: FactoryOptions<T> = {}) 
{
    const { items: itemsOrFunc = defaultItems } = options;
    return typeof itemsOrFunc === 'function' ? itemsOrFunc(defaultItems) : itemsOrFunc;
}
```

I am struggling with the return type of function in the 3 scenarios listed above. My goal is for the correct type to be inferred in each case but instead, I receive a union type. Is this possible?

```
// returns DefaultItems
const test1 = factory();
// Actual: DefaultItems | Item<string>[]
// Expected: Item<string>[]
const test2 = factory({ items: [foo] })
// Actual: DefaultItems | Item<number>[]
// Expected: Item<number>[]
const test3 = factory({ items: () => [num] })
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8AVAfFAvFA3lAbgIYA2ArhAFxQpQC%20A3ALABQLokUAggHYhyIBnLFABOEQgBMA9t2IhY8ZIV5oA2gF0mzdtAAiEAGaFSxYPwRDsYyTLlRV5pAOAiAltwDmaADQLESblIEACMIETRNFjZwaAAxQgBjYCkREAB5MGBXGQFUKAgAD3huCSFraVl5R2UQNXUMbBwWKBaoV0UBAH4qGgAfKAAKAYlDY1NzASoePg6ASiwMFFmtWijmBJzgKAMpKSpHZzdPBtwCEnIqAHIdqUu6LQ3uZyhAhH3FAKDQ8OE8IjJKFAAIwAJgAzPcWI9niMjCYzB0qPo4eMOsJVDdfK91GsDKRuElstxtolkqk8oViqUuLwJsJkWMEYI0AMpJkiZMoPEkil0uycqgTjhaPMmsxWlBoVs8O1BFRZRY0iJYviEsJYYy6bRhGysjktBKxMBSCJiTopAY2h0lSqCVhMNhrqq9dw7p0rYIbarhqN4RN5vLrcrVSs1gB6MOiCDG01CBl%20jpQzZQeDOIHCIw81IDZYsCNcJKkEhI32owRQfoHFzuLwaPORgCiBUgSQgEne-kONbqSaeW1TwBBGdJvIGMsR9hu6jos3rBeNxag8bLFgrfmQr2%20PeY%20abLfg7fXnxCYW3UpTEGcEOwmbJIDHHosVBzC3s2JnQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a conditional return type checking if `T` was `DefaultItems`:

```
function factory<T extends AnyItems = DefaultItems>(options: FactoryOptions<T> = {}): [T] extends [DefaultItems] ? DefaultItems : T {
```

Wrapping it in a tuple to prevent distribution, preventing it from returning `DefaultItems` if `T` is `DefaultItems | SomethingElse`. This makes it so that it only returns `DefaultItems`, if `T` is only `DefaultItems`.

With this method an assertion is required:

```
return (typeof itemsOrFunc === 'function' ? itemsOrFunc(defaultItems) : itemsOrFunc) as ReturnType<typeof factory<T>>;
```

If you dislike the use conditional types here or having to use assertions, consider using overloads as an alternative (which, in my opinion, should used anyways).

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdrEdW)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would an overload approach work in this case? In my actual code, the options object has a number of keys with similar default semantics.